# Linq to NHibernate ordering is not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

When executing the code below I get different results when I perform in memory and SQL ordering. Can anyone explain why that is. I expected the queries to return records in exactly the same order.

```
       IQueryable<WaitListListItem> query = GetQuery();

        query = query.OrderBy(f => f.CourseNo);

        int pageSize = 14;
        int startRecord = 6;

        IList<WaitListListItem> list1 = query.Skip(startRecord).Take(pageSize).ToList(); // database query paging
        IList<WaitListListItem> list2 = query.ToList().Skip(startRecord).Take(pageSize).ToList(); // In Memory paging

        Print(pageSize, list1, list2);

        int pageSize2 = 14;
        int startRecord2 = 0;

        IList<WaitListListItem> list3 = query.Skip(startRecord2).Take(pageSize2).ToList(); // database query paging
        IList<WaitListListItem> list4 = query.ToList(); // No Paging

        Print(pageSize2, list3, list4);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Further note. The order is correct in that the list is sorted by Course number alphabetically.However records containing the same course number

Comment: This seems to be problem with paging and not sorting. Sorting is done in DB in both cases. It is paging which is done in DB and in memory. Can you post the generated SQL for both?

Answer (score 1):

In memory sorting is likely to be different because of a number of reasons. Assuming that CourseNo is a string rather than a number:

1. Case sensitivity settings in the database
2. Culture settings when doing string comparisons
3. Ordering of equal records - the resulting order of such records should be considered random for all intents and purposes

As you have specified none of the above in your code example, it is hard to say exactly what is happening in your case, but if you expect the ordering to be exactly the same then you should ensure that each of the above issues are handled in the same manner in your database and your application.